# How to remove additional spacing around input type colour elements in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, color-picker, input-type-color

What styling on input `type="color"` is causing the additional spacing in Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge and how can it be mitigated?

Firefox seems to honour this better but due to the differance, changes need to ensure all major browsers normalise the appearance.

[image]

```css
input {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: 0 !important;
  outline: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" value="#bb0000" />
```

Comment: @tacoshy yeah, agreed. I was looking for any properties directly on the input field itself via dev tools yesterday when trying to find something that could eliminate this, but those special pseudo elements can't really be "found" that way.